# Reference Nested DIV for CSS Styling

Tags: html, css, elementor

Using Elementor I have a current HTML structure as per the below;

```
<div class="carousel-post">
    <div class="elementor-element-overlay">
        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <div class="elementor-posts-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to reference the class "elementor-posts-container" therefore, I have added class "carousel-post".

In my CSS I want to display "elementor-posts-container" as FLEX however, only this DIV which is under "carousel-post".

CSS

```
.carousel-post, .elementor-posts-container
```

The above works but targets all .elementor-posts-container

Comment: It should be <pre><code>.carousel-post .elementor-posts-container</code></pre>. Remove the comma.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect on styling. Am I missing something?

Comment: *Correction this doesn't have the desired effect I need. I need to display this class .elementor-posts-container to flex

Answer (score 0):

***** Just an Explanation *****

Adding this as an answer since I am not able to add formatting.

It should be

```
.carousel-post .elementor-posts-container
```

. Remove the comma.

1. When the code is

   ```
   .carousel-post, .elementor-posts-container
   ```

   , with the **comma (,)** it means match either of the two.
2. When you remove the **comma (,)**, it means match the child within the parent. -->>> **This will match your usecase**
3. To get a direct match of the direct parent-child relationship (when you need it in the future), do

   ```
   .carousel-post > .elementor-posts-container
   ```

   . This matches all the ".elementor-posts-container" divs directly within ".carousel-post".

***** EDIT *****

Doesn't this work:

```
.carousel-post .elementor-posts-container{
    display: flex;
}
```

The above code means, all ".elementor-posts-container" inside ".carousel-post" should be "display flex".

Comment: This should work, but it doesn't unfortunately. I'm stumped.

Comment: Wrap your code in 3 backticks (each site) for comments ;)